# HTML input list disappears when populated by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have populated list of input list like the code below.
Then when I try to click on input field and open the dropdown with list, the list opens and closes within a second. I am not sure whether this is a problem with CSS or Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         function getES(){
         var a = new Array(15).fill("0");
             var options;
             for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
         options += '<option value="'+a[i]+'" />';
         document.getElementById('ESList').innerHTML = options;
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="/action_page.php" method="get" onclick="getES()">
         <input list="ESList" name="browser">
         <datalist id="ESList">                      
         </datalist>
         <input type="submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you're showing the list on click, and then immediately destroying it, causing it to collapse. When it collapses it doesn't automatically pop up again when you repopulate. What is it you're trying to do? The code you're using is going to give you nothing but trouble. It's awkward and is, I'm sorry to say, very much bad practice. It's most likely that you're new and aren't aware of a better way to build it, but you're going to paint yourself in a corner if you don't revisit how you're building this thing.

Comment: You should try a templating engine if you have a server, or run a script on the page load which populates the input options.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the function every time someone clicks within the form:

`onclick="getES()"`

Try moving the JS to the bottom and running on load:

```
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
         <input list="ESList" name="browser">
         <datalist id="ESList">                      
         </datalist>
         <input type="submit">
      </form>
        <script>
         var a = new Array(15).fill("0");
             var options;
             for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
         options += '<option value="'+a[i]+'" />';
         document.getElementById('ESList').innerHTML = options;

      </script>
   </body>

</html>
```